# How to pass the type of useState variables/setters from to child component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this parent component that uses useState:

```
export type Info = {
  color: 'red' | 'yellow' | 'green' | 'blue'
  isActive: boolean
}

const ParentComponent: React.FC =(props: any) => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState(0)
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    color: 'red',
    isActive: false,
  })

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      tab={tab}
      setTab={setTab}
      info={info}
      setInfo={setInfo}
    />
  )
}
```

It renders this child component:

```
interface Props {
  tab: number
  setTab: (p: number) => void
  info: Info
  setInfo: (p: Info | ((p: Info) => any)) => void
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  tab,
  setTab,
  info,
  setInfo,
}) => (
  /* some JSX */
)
```

Right now I have to type all the props manually for `ChildComponent`, even though the types are already defined in `ParentComponent`. Is there a way to pass the typings of `tab`, `setTab`, `info`, and `setInfo` from `ParentComponent` to `ChildComponent`?

Comment: Yes you can easily access your `setInfo` and `setTab` as function in child component like `setInfo({color:green,isActive:true})` and `setTab(2)` you get your value in parent component and child as props.

Comment: @SanatGupta I'm not asking about how to use `setInfo` and `setTab`, what I'm trying to achieve is being able to get the typings for `setInfo` and `setTab` automatically (without having to write the type in the interface myself)

Comment: @theopenroad any chance that my answer might help?

Answer (score 0):

`ChildComponent` will not be able to directly infer the typings from `ParentComponent`. However, what you can do to achieve a similar result would be to define a common interface for both `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`.

First, you define a common interface/type for your `ParentComponent` state.

```
export interface CommonState {
  tab: number;
  info: Info;
}
```

Then, we use the interface when we declare the `useState` hooks in ParentComponent.

```
const [tab, setTab] = useState<CommonState['tab']>(0)
const [info, setInfo] = useState<CommonState['info']>({
  color: 'red',
  isActive: false,
});
```

Then, on your `ChildComponent`, instead of declaring a brand new type for the child, it could extend off the `CommonState` interface, such that the typings are shared.

```
interface Props extends CommonState {
  setTab: (p: number) => void
  setInfo: (p: Info | ((p: Info) => any)) => void
}
```